# Question about explicit notation of averaged energy conditions integrals

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, notation, integration, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Beyond the basics of  general relativity, we rapid encounter the  so called Averaged energy conditions. The mathematics of these quantities are related to line and volume integrals.

As given by [1], violations of the pointwise energy conditions led to the averaging of the energy conditions over timelike or lightlike geodesics.

For instance, consider the *null energy condition* (NEC):

$$T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} \geq 0 \tag{1}$$

(where $k^{\mu}$ are light-like vectors and $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor). The process of "averaging" a energy condition is simply a matter of integration of $(1)$:

$$\int_{\lambda} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} d\lambda \geq 0 \tag{2}$$

So, the integral $(2)$ are called *Averaged Null Energy Condition* (ANEC). Furthermore, the integral $(2)$ gives no information of "total amount" of energy-condition violating matter, then we need a volume quantifier which express the notion of "total amount" [1]. This notion, then, is expressed by volume integrals of $(2)$:

$$\int_{V} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} dV \geq 0 \tag{3}$$

My doubt isn't about the physics, but rather, about notation.

Well, integral $(2)$ is a line integral and integral $(3)$ are a volume integral. Therefore, roughly speaking, the basics of multivariable calculus are valid.
Then, my guess for notation of $(2)$ and $(3)$ are:

$$\int_{\lambda} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} d\lambda = \int^{{x^{0}_{2}}}_{x^{0}_{1}} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} \sqrt{-g}dx^{0} \tag{4} $$

$$\int_{V} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} dV = \int^{x^{3}_{2}}_{x^{3}_{1}} \int^{h_{2}(x^{3})}_{h_{1}(x^{3})} \int^{g_{2}(x^{3},x^{2})}_{g_{1}(x^{3},x^{2})} \int^{q_{2}(x^{3},x^{2},x^{1})}_{q_{1}(x^{3},x^{2},x^{1})} T_{\mu \nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} \sqrt{-g}dx^{0}dx^{1}dx^{2}dx^{3} \tag{5}$$

So, the integrals written as $(4)$ and $(5)$ are totally correct?

[1] F.S.N Lobo, **Exotic solutions of General Relativity: Travesable wormholes and warp drive spacetimes**, https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4474

Answer (score 1):

The averaged energy conditions are given by integrating the Raychaudhuri equation along a geodesic. The constraint asks for the expansion of the congruence of the curves to focus. Free falling observers get closer to each other, i.e. gravity is assumed always attractive. A timelike geodesic uses the proper time $\tau$ as parameter of integration along the curve, a null geodesic an affine parameter $\lambda$.

As for the ANEC (averaged null energy condition) the integral is performed using an affine parameter. However I do not think that equation $(4)$ is correct. The expression $\sqrt{-g} dx^0$ is not an invariant (refer below).

Instead equation $(5)$ seems correct. A tensor volume element in a manifold of dimension $n$ is given by $\sqrt{-g} d^n x$ where $g$ is the determinant of the tensor metric $g_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: What suppose to mean, physically, integration of whole Raychaudhuri equation along a line (geodesic)? Also, how can I write properly the equation $(4)$?

Comment: Physically the integration of the Raychaudhuri equation along a geodesic means a change in the convergence or divergence of the curves. As for equation $(4)$ you have to perform the integral along a null geodesic, for instance a radial null geodesic by expressing the affine parameter vs. the radial coordinate.